# Why is this function parameter not treated as local variable to this function?

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have a function which returns an integer pointer type:

```
int* f(int a, int b){

   int *result;

   result = &a;

   *result += b;

   return result;
}
```

and when I call this on main:

```
int main(){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 2;

    int *result = f(a,b);

    printf("The result is: %d \n", *result);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives me the correct output(in this case 7). I was under the impression that by assigning the address of the parameter `a` to `result` I would get a segmentation fault when I ran this function.

My assumption is that C treats function parameters as local in scope to the function definition. But, I see that this is not the case so why is this specific program working ?

I'm using Code::Blocks 16.01 with gcc compiler.

Comment: Why did you think it's going to give a segmentation fault?

Comment: @mangusta It returns the address of the parameter to the function. It surprisingly works on my system. This is UB as far as C is concerned.

Comment: The memory previously occupied by the parameter `a` didn't just vanish.  It's still there, and it happens to still be accessible and to not yet have been overwritten.

Comment: Just because it works on your machine doesn't mean it isn't *undefined behaviour*. This works by fluke, but it's invalid.

Comment: If you put a `puts("a");` in between calling `f()` and `printf()`, then it returns 0.

Comment: Keep in mind that invalid code is generally not *guaranteed* to segfault.

Comment: Your first two sentences contradict each other. Your first sentence says that 7 is the correct output. But then your second sentence says that 7 is not the correct output. Which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because it works on your machine doesn't mean it isn't *undefined behaviour*. This works by fluke, but it's invalid.

It may produce the correct result because that stack is not overwitten or otherwise mangled by the time you do something later on.

For example, if you make another function call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int noop(int x, int y) {
   return x + y;
}

int* f(int a, int b){

   int *result;

   result = &a;

   *result += b;

   return result;
}

int main(){
    int a = 5;
    int b = 2;

    // Do something with undefined behaviour
    int *result = f(a,b);

    // Do something else which uses the stack and/or the same memory
    int x = 10;
    int y = 11;
    int z = noop(x, y);

    printf("The result is: %d \n", *result);

    return 0;
}
```

Now the output gets stomped with the definition of `x` which coincidentally takes the same piece of memory so the output is `10`. As this is undefined behaviour, though, *anything could happen*, including a crash.